# Rust-Analyzer expansion pack is failing to load workspace What's the reason?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

[image]

I've tried reinstalling Rust and reinstalling the expansion pack
I also tried to recreate the project file. However, this error has not been corrected.
Why can't I read the Cargo.toml file when it exists?

Comment: Do you have Rust installed?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes. I installed it by default using the command curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh.

Comment: Try to run `cargo --version` in your terminal.

Comment: Cargo 1.61.0 (a028ae4 2022-04-29) works normally.

Comment: And if you `cd` into your project directory (`rust_learn`), does it still work?

Comment: Yes, I checked that Cargo build and run are working. However, the expansion pack still does not work